# onClick with CTRL button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I have an issue with the button clicking with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key.
The form is being posted twice. (on the same tab and on the new tab)

I don't want to go to new tab (in order to avoid twice submission)

I tried return false;

```
onClick="document.form[0].submit(); return false;"
```

but no success.

Thanks for any help.

Here is 
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GZuvx/)

Comment: The default behaviour for a button of type "submit" is submitting the form it belongs to .. What is the purpose of this inline onClick event ?

Comment: try using preventDefault() but not in inline-script

Comment: @f00bar yes.. its just used to avoid ctrl click some how.

Comment: I only get one form submit. Which browser are you using?

Comment: @josef: Latest version of chrome.

Comment: @C-link: how? can u do in jsfiddle?

Comment: @f00bar: after removing onclick, still going to the next tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try next:

1. replace 
   `document.form[0]`
   by
   `document.forms[0]`;
2. add `name` attribute for your input tag;
3. change your button `type` attribute to `button`

[my corrected JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darkfisk/GZuvx/1/)

Comment: Thanks.. worked fine. I was just missing 's' in form[0]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#submit').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  document.form[0].submit();
});
```

Comment: May be this has to be underlined ... The button id is "submit" but not "button" `:/`

Comment: A more general approach would be to listen for "submit" events on the whole form.

Comment: Same problem with this too. May the because the form post in on server side.

Comment: also try, e.stopPropagation();